# AngularJS is working fine on Chrome, IE, Mozilla and Edge but not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the Controller code which clears the item if value includes '(Result not found)' and pops up an alert; All this works fine on Chrome, Edge, Mozilla but doesn't work on IE. I am new to coding and all, would appreciate your guidance here. Thank you in advance.

```
if (item.Value.includes("(Result not found)")){
            $scope.clearItem();
        alert("No Result found, please contact HelpDesk");
    }
```

Comment: Do you receive/see any error(s) in your developer console?

Comment: Probably `includes` is not supported in IE try `item.Value.indexOf("(Result not found)") !== -1`

Comment: Brill! Thanks a ton 'jcubic', it worked.